How to Ensure Sequential Player IDs in Photon when Players Join/Leave a Room (Without Gaps in IDs)?
I'm working on a multiplayer game using Photon in Unity, where players join a room and spawn at specific positions based on their ActorNumber. However, when a player leaves the room, and a new player joins, I am encountering an issue where the player IDs (i.e., the ActorNumber) don't always follow a sequential order, which causes gaps in the spawn positions (for example, I might get ActorNumber 1, then 3, then 4).
The problem occurs because I want to assign a spawn position to each player based on their ActorNumber from a predefined dictionary of positions. When a player leaves and another joins, the new player may receive a previously used ActorNumber, which can lead to missing positions in the sequence.
So what I'm trying to do is:
If for example there are 3 players in photon room then according to the logic of ActorNumber it will look like this:

Actor 1 gets ActorNumber 1
Actor 2 gets ActorNumber 2
Actor 3 gets ActorNumber 3

But if player 2 for example leaves the room and a new player comes after him then he will be:
Actor 4 gets ActorNumber 4, but and I need it to be
Actor 4 gets ActorNumber 2 because like I said actor 2 is out.
Here is the code i use:
public class SpawnPlayers : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public GameObject playerPRE;

    private Dictionary<int, Vector3> waitingRoomSpawnPositions = new Dictionary<int, Vector3>()
    {
        {1, new Vector3(0, 0, 0)},
        {2, new Vector3(0.85f, 0, 1.25f)},
        {3, new Vector3(-0.85f, 0, 1.25f)},
        {4, new Vector3(-1.7f, 0, 2.5f)},
        {5, new Vector3(1.7f, 0, 2.5f)},
        {6, new Vector3(0.85f, 0, 3.75f)},
        {7, new Vector3(-0.85f, 0, 3.75f)},
        {8, new Vector3(0, 0, 2.5f)}
    };

    public void PlayerSpawn()
    {
        // int actorNumber = actorNumberManager.AssignActorNumber(); // Assign a unique actor number.
        int actorNumber = PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber;

        Vector3 spawnPosition = Vector3.zero;

        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Home")
        {
            waitingRoomSpawnPositions.TryGetValue(actorNumber, out spawnPosition);
            spawnPosition = new Vector3(spawnPosition.x, spawnPosition.y, spawnPosition.z);
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerPRE.name, spawnPosition, Quaternion.Euler(0, 160f, 0));
        }
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        PlayerSpawn();
    }
}


I would rather not rely on the IDs given by photon but rather use some Room properties and there you can simply ensure you fill gaps .. simply store them flags like spot1taken and if according player leaves the room the master client updates the room properties and sets the flags to false .. then you just have to go through the flags and pick the first unset one for a new player

If a player leaves, you add his "freed" number to a collection. When a new player arrives, if the "collection" has number(s), you issue one from the collection (and delete that entry); else, issue a new number.

@GerrySchmitz the only issue with this (in photon specific) is that there is no collections in the room properties. You would either have to do this on a master client - but then if he leaves the information might be gone - or as said in the room properties you can store these flags and "iterate" through them until you find the next free one ... of course you can use a loop and just do e.g. for(var i = 0; i < MAXPLAYERS; i++){ var flagName = $"Slot {i}"; if(int.Parse(roomProperties[flagName]) == 0 { ... claim } } for example

I create "add ons" via "static" Dictionaries that are "keyed" to an object's "id". I need "collections" of who fired on who, but not every unit "can fire". When someone fires, a "relation" is created in 2 dictionaries that answers questions like: who is firing on me; who am I hitting; who is nearer; who is doing more damage. The "static" dictionaries are just "out there". They don't depend on a "room". They're "global".

A "static" class library makes a great "data store" in this case. (IMO)
